# regex for string which consist of 1 to 4 non-zero numeric characters or 1 to 4 non-zero numeric characters and 1 alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regex for strings that consist of 1 to 4 non-zero numeric characters or 1 to 4 non-zero numeric characters and 1 alphabetic, but I am stuck in how to fix length of the alphabetic characters to one.

```
"(^[1-9]{1,4}$|^[[a-zA-Z][1-9]{1,4}]$)"
```

I tried this way, but its not working; it is validating only strings that consist of 1 to 4 non-zero numeric characters.

Comment: What about order of characters? 1234, 123u, 12u3,u123 -> all acceptable, or order is important?

Comment: All acceptable like 1234,123u4,12u34,1u234,u1234,1243u are valid string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:\d{1,4}|(?=\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*$)[\da-zA-Z]{2,5})$
```

You need a `lookahead` for this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/2

Comment: Great, i knew that it is not so trivial, so i don't understand why this question is voted for closing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your best chance is to test your regex using an online tool, like http://www.regexr.com/.

Besides, what you're trying to achieve can be done like this : `([a-zA-Z]?[1-9]{1,4})`

Explanations :

- `[a-zA-Z]` Means a-z alphabetical character
- `?` Means 0 or 1 of the previous set (what was missing in your test)
- `[1-9]{1,4}` Means 1 to 4 numerical characters, as you mention it

Comment: thanks for response but still one issue is there.I mean alphabetical character need not be the first character.It can be anywhere in string but should come only once or none like "a1234" "1a222","12a22","123a2","1234a","1234" should be valid string